# How to hide/disable one TextBlock control from WPF usercontrol?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a Toggle button with title, i created the the ToggleSwitch.xaml UserControl so that i can use them in multiple pages. Every thing is going perfect.

But in one page i need to show toggle switch button in DataGrid so that user can change the state but when in use ToggleSwitch UserControl the TextBox also takes some space making my design look very bad.

I just want to show the ToggleSwitch button on DataGrid not the TextBox with some text.

I want to hide the TextBox so that i may not effect my design.

Thank You if any one can help, You can see the code snippet below.

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,-23,0">
    <ToggleButton Name="toggleButton"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ToggleButton_OnClick" IsChecked="{Binding Path=StateChecked}" Cursor="Hand" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Height="13" Width="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Name="tbText" Text="{Binding Path=ControlText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="279" Margin="15,8,0,7"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: perhaps you could add a Boolean in your user control and when it's marked it will hide your textbox

Comment: Can you please elaborate more @DarkTemplar ?

Comment: I need to see the xaml of your user control and I will write an example.

Comment: Visibility = Collapsed

Comment: Visibility = Collapsed, collapse whole usercontrol, i want just to hide the textbox from the usercontrol @AnjumSKhan

Comment: @DarkTemplar You can see the xaml in the posted question section (sorry for the late reply as i was busy with other tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Dependency Properties`. Bind the visibility of your textbox to a dependency property in the user control.

First create the dependency property like this :

```
public Visibility TextBlockVisibilityProperty
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(TextBlockVisibilityPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextBlockVisibilityPropertyProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextBlockVisibilityProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBlockVisibilityPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextBlockVisibilityProperty", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MaintenancePage), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Then in xaml bind the property to `textblock` visibility like below

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,-23,0">
    <ToggleButton Name="toggleButton"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ToggleButton_OnClick" IsChecked="{Binding Path=StateChecked}" Cursor="Hand" Style="{DynamicResource AnimatedSwitch}" Height="13" Width="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Name="tbText" Text="{Binding Path=ControlText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="279" Margin="15,8,0,7" Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibilityProperty}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Now when reusing the control in xaml, set the   `TextBlockVisibilityProperty` while defining the control as required. This will hide the `textblock`.